# How to distinguish between isomorphic and homotopic chain complexes?

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

Consider two chain complexes $A_\bullet$ and $B_\bullet$ in your favorite category $\mathcal{C}$ (say abelian groups, or vector spaces). The question is:

> **Q1:** Are there standard techniques to show that **$A_\bullet$ and $B_\bullet$ are *not* isomorphic**?

To avoid trivial cases, we may assume that $A_\bullet$ and $B_\bullet$ are homotopic (or at least have the same homology, assuming homology makes sense in $\mathcal{C}$) and that $A_\bullet$ and $B_\bullet$ have isomorphic chain spaces.

Note: the question is motivated by the similar question on non-*homotopic* complexes, where an answer could be "compute the respective homologies (assuming it makes sense) and hope they are distinct: in many practical cases, this is enough".

Added: to give a more precise question:

> **Q2:** Are there examples of homotopic complexes with isomorphic chain spaces, but which are not isomorphic?

Comment: In general, I think this would be quite hard. Homology is, after all, the primary invariant for telling apart two chain complexes.

Comment: You are probably right in general. But I wonder whether this can at least be done in specific cases. Actually, a less vague question could be: "what are examples of homotopic complexes with isomorphic chain spaces, but which are not isomorphic?"

Comment: As a note, if you are wanting to start with isomorphic chain spaces, you are really asking for techniques for distinguishing the isomorphism type of $(A,d)$ to begin with, since you're asking "Given a chain homotopy equivalence from $(A,d)$ to $(A, \delta)$, are the complexes necessarily isomorphic/how does one tell if they are or aren't?" I'm no expert on the algebra of the situation, but this reminds me of the question "Is a homotopy equivalence between manifolds (homotopy equivalent to) an isomorphism (pick your category of manifolds)?" which is the subject of surgery theory.